# Get an email from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

A Newbie here

This is my problem

Let say my string is

```
var string = "this is a string that contains many different words
domain@gmail.com an I want just the email";
```

what I want is a regex or something different that gets just this `domain@gmail.com`

I've tried many things but none has worked

this is the last one I've tried

```
var myRegexp = /@(.*)/;
var match = myRegexp.exec(string);
if(match)
  console.log(match[1]);
```

this always returns null or undefined

can anyone help me out

EDIT

I want something that search for everything before and after @ and stops on blank space

thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you search for "email regex" you will find something.

Comment: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html For a complete solution.

Comment: Try `var match = string.match(/ \S+@(\S+)/);`. Also use `console.log(match[0])` to see whole match.

Comment: What if the email address comes right at the end of the string?

Comment: I tried. it works with @jusopi answer

Comment: jusopi answer Worked for me, Thanks all for your answer and @terminija no I didn't want to validate an email I wanted to get one from a long string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
emails = str.match(/(\S[^\s@]*@\S+)/gi)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the surrounding parentheses? Also, why not do `/\S+?@\S+/`?

Comment: Nice. this worked as well !

Comment: @torazaburo I generally use the parentheses out of habit.  It's useful in case maybe they wanted to add `<a href="mailto:` linkages within a body of text.